# How can AngularJS 1.3 throw runtime errors on missing controller methods called from the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring, runtime-error

In Angular.js we usually call methods from HTML code, e.g. `<a ng-click="fooCtrl.bar()">foo</a>` (here using the Controller As syntax).

However no error is thrown if the `bar()` method is missing from `fooCtrl`. It is a source of multiple regression bugs, especially after code refactoring.

Do you know how to force Angular.js 1.3 to throw runtime errors on missing controller methods called from the view?

Comment: it's about errors in expressions in the view at all (not about methods only). I am also interested to find solution how to debug view expressions in angular.

Comment: a related question that still doesn't solve mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227596/why-dont-angularjs-errors-in-the-html-show-up-in-the-console

Comment: This discussion states that it is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297108/angularjs-ng-click-silently-eats-errors